# Slick Slider - Disappearing <p> Tag Safari

Tags: jquery, slider, carousel

Im using Slick Slider on a site, with the cliché slider on the index page, leading off to subsequent pages. So in the slider I want an image, with a caption underneath. That bit was easy enough to set up, but in Safari, while scrolling and (it seems) until mouseOut, the captions disappear?

Any thoughts?

Demo: http://thomasfearn.co.uk/bw/index_2.php